# page layout auto change when trying to change browser zoom out

Tags: css, layout, browser

I designed a responsive web page which is best viewed in 1680px screen. But when i am going to zoom out the page using view menu of firefox, The page layout is auto change with two columns also the contents of the page is changed to worst design.

The url of the page is

http://www.tuitionok.com/website-demo/indofast/

Screen Shot of the page which is best view in 1680px or greater px.
(this is the layout which i want in all pixcel)

[image: this is the layout which i want in all pixcel]

Screen Shot of the page which is worst / not proper in  less than 1680px.

[image]

I want the layout will be same which is shown in (1680px) in all resolution (zoom out/zoom in).

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to make change in your CSS Class or i would suggest to use bootstrap, it is not too much complicated to align using bootstrap for eg

for mast head you can specify bootstrap class in one row and column space col-lg-12

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
 ---- Your content goes here
 </div>
</div>
```

please refer bootstrap documentation for more details from here http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Grid System layout for perfect responsive website,
So you can use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

See also http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootstrap-alternatives/